# Checkbox check and uncheck to remove values in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying this React plus typescript code.

When I click a checkbox data added to cites but if I uncheck any checkbox, all data is removed from `cites`:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
const [cities, setCities] = useState<object[]>([]); 
const handleCheck = (e: any) => { 
    if (e.target.checked) { setCities((oldArray:any) => [...oldArray, e.target.value]); } 
    else { removeCities(e); console.log(cities) } 
}
const removeCities = (e:any) => { setCities([...cities.filter((city: any) => city !== e.target.value)]) }
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <form>
      </form> <input type="checkbox" value={row.booking_id} onChange={(e) => {handleCheck(e)}} /> </>
       
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here if I click uncheck in checkbox value 8, the value is automatically removed. I need the previous value to not be removed

Answer (score 0):

Your state should be inside the function component, something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]); 
  const handleCheck = (e) => { 
      if (e.target.checked) { setCities((oldArray) => [...oldArray, e.target.value]); } 
      else { removeCities(e); console.log(cities) } 
  }
  const removeCities = (e) => { setCities([...cities.filter((city) =>
     city !== e.target.value)]) }

  
  return (
    <>
      <form>
      </form> 
      <input type="checkbox" 
      value={row.booking_id} onChange={(e) => {handleCheck(e)}} /> </>
       
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also your jsx is wrong so try to fix it and try again

Comment: Argument of type '(oldArray: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(oldArray: any) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)